# Integrating Tauri for a Text Analysis Application on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, user-interface, tauri

I'm working on a Windows desktop application using **Tauri**, aiming to build a simple text analysis tool. While I don't need advanced NLP capabilities like **Grammarly**, I would like to send user input to a server and receive a JSON response with various data.

Here are the key points I'm trying to address:

- **Sending User Input to a Server:**

I want to send user input (text) from my Tauri application to a server for analysis. What would be the best way to implement this client-server communication in a Tauri application?

- **Receiving JSON Response:**

Once the server processes the input, I expect to receive a JSON response with analysis results. How can I handle and parse this JSON response within my Tauri application?

- **Gadget Icon Integration:**

I'd like to implement a gadget icon for my application, similar to how Grammarly appears in the system tray. Are there specific Tauri APIs or best practices for integrating a gadget icon into a Tauri application on Windows?

- **Reading User Input Seamlessly:**

To provide a smooth user experience, I'd like to read user input seamlessly. What Tauri features or considerations should I be aware of to capture and process user input efficiently?

- **Underlining and Highlighting Text in Other Windows Applications:**

As an additional feature, I want to implement the ability to underline and highlight text in any window application, similar to Grammarly. Are there Tauri APIs or external libraries that can assist with this task?

---

If anyone has experience with similar tasks using Tauri or has insights into these specific challenges, including underlining and highlighting text, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: You should use [HTTP API](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/http) to communicate with the server. The rest is JS.